# ASP.NET MVC. Как подключить БД Oracle к проекту?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, oracle12c

Есть база данных Oracle, в ней несколько таблиц. Как можно данную БД подключить к своему  проекту ?
Пробовал делать как в данной статье [тут](https://tech2677.wordpress.com/2016/12/04/asp-net-mvc-5-entity-framework-connect-with-oracle-database-database-first-approach/). Но застрял на 4-ом шаге т.к. у меня VS не видит Oracle.
В чем может быть проблема ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вдруг поможет по этим ссылкам https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm  или здесь про Nuget пакеты https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli  или руководство https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/

Comment: так же тут https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/CodeFirst/index.html